# set of n-linear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, linear-equation

I have some trouble on setting of n-linear equations in matlab.I don't know how can I declare in matlab.I need matlab code for setting of n-linear equations..

Comment: Don't duplicate your comments, and add a homework tag if appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write n-linear equations as one matrix equation to solve it. Here you can find great example: 
http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/09/13/matlab-basics-video-solving-linear-equations/ (video!)

See also these pages:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equation

Comment: I have n-equations and n-unknowns .What I must do is that define these equations so that when the input is entered,the output will be given. This is the sample input&output of our programme.This will help to recognise our problem. A1X1 + A2X2 .... + AnXn = B1 . . . AnXn ............... = Bn that we have n-unknowns and n equations and I must define this equations in matlab.

Comment: SO? What's the problem? Read the wiki... TUrning n-equations into matrix equation is one of the most basic problems of linear algebra. If you can't do so, then your problem is in poor mathematics, not matlab...

Answer (score 1):

You can solve a linear system in various ways, depending on whether there exists a unique solution or not.

A simple way is by reducing it to reduced-echelon form (rref).

Consider the system:

```
 x + 5y = 4
2x -  y = 1
```

You can write the coefficient matrix A, and the RHS, B as follows: (`'` is the transpose operator)

```
>> A = [1 5; 2 -1]

A =

     1     5
     2    -1

>> B = [4 1]'

B =

     4
     1
```

You can write it as an augmented matrix (A|B):

```
>> horzcat(A,B)

ans =

     1     5     4
     2    -1     1
```

And then find the REF(A|B)

```
>> rref(ans)

ans =

    1.0000         0    0.8182
         0    1.0000    0.6364
```

And hence x ~ .8182, y ~ .6364.

Comment: I have n-equations and n-unknowns .What I must do is that define these equations so that when the input is entered,the output will be given. This is the sample input&output of our programme.This will help to recognise our problem.


A1X1 + A2X2 .... + AnXn = B1
.
.
.
AnXn ............... = Bn

that we have n-unknowns and n equations and I must define this equations in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely fastest way to solve linear equations in MATLAB is simply to setup your equation on the form

```
AX = B
```

and then solve by

```
X = A\B
```

You can issue

```
help mldivide
```

to find more information on matrix division and what limitations it has.

Comment: But that will only work if there is a unique solution. (I.e. A is invertible).

Comment: @Alex: Yes, and it will produce a warning saying so. It will perform better than inv(A)*B though. I checked your solution as well, and it suffers from the same problem (while it is longer to type).

Answer (score 0):

A Code for iterative method Guase Seidel
tol is error tolerance
x0 is first guess for solution

---

```
 function seidel(A,b,x0,tol,itmax)
%Solve the system  Ax=b using the Gauss-Seidel iteration method.
clc
% =======================================================
% Programmer : A. Ziaee mehr
%

help seidel
n=length(b);
x=zeros(n,1);
%fprintf('\n')
disp('The augumented matrix is = ')
Augm=[A b]
Y=zeros(n,1);
Y=x0;   
for  k=1:itmax +1
    for ii=1:n
        S=0;
        for jj=1:ii-1
            S=S+A(ii,jj)*x(jj);
        end
        for jj=ii+1:n
            S=S+A(ii,jj)*x0(jj);
        end
        if (A(ii,ii)==0)
            break
        end
        x(ii)=(-S+b(ii))/A(ii,ii);
    end
    err=abs(norm(x-x0));
    rerr=err/(norm(x)+eps);
    x0=x;
    Y=[Y x];
    if(rerr<tol)
        break;
    end
end
% Print the results
if (A(ii,ii)==0)
    disp('division by zero')
elseif (k==itmax+1)
    disp('No convergence')
else
    %fprintf('\n')
    disp('The solution vector are : ')
    fprintf('\n')
    disp('iter    0       1            2          3           4    ... ');
    fprintf('\n')
    for ii=1:n
        fprintf('%1.0f= ',ii);
        fprintf('%10.6f ',Y(ii,1:k+1));
        fprintf('\n')
    end
    fprintf('\n')
    disp(['The method converges after ',num2str(k),' iterations to'])
    x
end
```

Comment: itmax is maximum number of iteration that prevent programm to go to a unfinishrd loop.